# How to detect carrier name from a incoming call in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-telephony, carrier

Is it possible to detect carrier name from incoming calls using core telephony or anything classes? 
I would like to visually get a telephoner's carrier name in iPhone after ringing off.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This type of information is available through any type of caller id service.  I do know there are some services out there that allow you to lookup what carrier a block of numbers is assigned to, however, with number portability the data is not always accurate.

Here is an older blog post where a similar question was asked, and there really hasnt been any movement in the arena since then.

http://sms411.net/2006/07/finding-out-someones-carrier/